# angular disable button on dynamic list

Tags: angular

My list is taking info from external API, Im creating it dynamically, When I click on the 'li' element (I create 10 of them) with (click) method bunch of info shows up (second ul list). The problem is that I want to disable all other elements (all other 9) that aren't clicked, ofc until I unclick that one I clicked before. Summing I want be able to click only 1 element at once others must be disable for that moment.
Could someone explain/show me how to do this?

```
<ng-container>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="exteriorUL" *ngFor="let planet of results$; let i = index;">
      <li (click)="hidden[i] = !hidden[i]">
          <b class="btn btn-success">{{planet.name}}</b>
      </li>
      <ul class="interiorUL" [hidden]="!hidden[i]">
        <li>
            <span>Rotation period:</span> {{planet.rotation_period}} h
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Orbital period:</span> {{planet.orbital_period}} days
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Climate:</span> {{planet.climate}}
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Planet terrain:</span> {{planet.terrain}}
        </li>
        <li>
          <span>Population:</span> {{planet.population}}
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Gravity:</span> {{planet.gravity}}
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Diameter:</span> {{planet.diameter}} km
        </li>

        <hr>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: " others must be disable for that moment." you mean other li will not be clickable?

Comment: exactly, other cant be clickable for that moment, uless I will unlick that one i clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

TS:

```
isAnyItemClicked:boolean = false;
clickedItem:string = 'Mercury'; // I guessed the name Mercury, set the appropiate name which you want to enable

clickItem(){
  if(this.clickedItem == ''){
     this.isAnyItemClicked = false
  } else {
     this.isAnyItemClicked = true
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<li (click)="clickItem();clickedItem= planet.name" [class.disabled]="isAnyItemClicked && clickedItem != planet.name">...</li>
```

CSS:

```
.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Comment: it blocking all of them, but idk why cause it looks smart and should be working

Comment: Set like this `clickedItem:string='Mercury';` set the first li name from TS

Comment: i know i understand ur code, but it block all elements also the one i click

Comment: Have you tried this: `clickedItem:string='Mercury'`

Comment: when i wrote clickedItem:string='Mercury';, it's working very good, there must be some mistake doing it dynamic

Comment: While you have fetched data from api, add this: `this.clickedItem = results[0].name`. This will make it dynamic

Comment: this.clickedItem = res['results'][0].name  it refers to first planet

Comment: Yes.. Tell me which one do you want to enable. Give the exact requirement

Comment: not which one, I want to click any from that list of 10 and disable all others at this moment. When I unclick that one I want to be able to click any of them again, but only 1 at once

Comment: In that way, you have to enable all of them at first and while any one of them is clicked, others will be disabled right? I am editing the answer

Comment: Try the modified answer, `[class.disabled]="isAnyItemClicked && clickedItem != planet.name"` and in TS: `isAnyItemClicked:boolean = false;`

Comment: almost perfect!, but when i unclick button, other stay still disabled, they dont turn enable again

Comment: I have modified the answer. I am not finding any button in your code. Of you have any button, clicking which you want to enable all li, add `(click)="clickedItem=''"`. It's better if you create a demo code snippet in stackbiltz

Comment: Your stackbilts isn't working. Instead of api call, u can put dummy data

Comment: will be way faster, when i update it to github: https://github.com/drozdzyk667/AngularPlanets

Comment: I will download your github project after 7 hrs and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: hahaha, we just lack clearing planet.name somewhere to default = ' ' empty string

Comment: As I mentioned button, clicking which  `(click)="clickedItem=''"`

Comment: solved it adding- > clickItem(){
     this.isAnyItemClicked = !this.isAnyItemClicked;
}      btw big thanks for helping me, I couldnt do this without ur help Thanks once again !

Answer (score 0):

Simply hold a value in a variable, and let that variable decide which li is displayed :

```js
currentListItem = 'name';
```

```html
<li *ngIf="currentListItem === 'name' (click)='currentListItem = 'name'">...</li>
<li *ngIf="currentListItem === 'climate' (click)='currentListItem = 'climate'">...</li>
<li *ngIf="currentListItem === 'terrain' (click)='currentListItem = 'terrain'">...</li>
```